# How to store cv::Scalar objects in a Map in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, dictionary, data-structures, collections

I want to store randomly generated Scalar values in a map. But the following attempt gives me a compile error.

```
RNG rng(0xFFFFFFFF);
std::map<Scalar, int> segmentColors;

Scalar randomColorTemp1 = randomColor(rng);
Scalar randomColorTemp2 = randomColor(rng);

segmentColors.insert(pair<Scalar, int>(randomColorTemp1, 1));
segmentColors.insert(pair<Scalar, int>(randomColorTemp1, 1));
```

Error report is as follows.

```
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef(193): error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const cv::Scalar' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          e:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\operations.hpp(3193): could be 'bool cv::operator <(const cv::FileNodeIterator &,const cv::FileNodeIterator &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          e:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp(1303): or       'cv::MatExpr cv::operator <(const cv::Mat &,const cv::Mat &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          e:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp(1304): or       'cv::MatExpr cv::operator <(const cv::Mat &,double)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          e:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp(1305): or       'cv::MatExpr cv::operator <(double,const cv::Mat &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          e:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp(1984): or       'bool cv::operator <(const cv::MatConstIterator &,const cv::MatConstIterator &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(const cv::Scalar, const cv::Scalar)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstddef(192) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Kty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=cv::Scalar
1>  ,            _Ty=cv::Scalar
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\map(228) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::less<_Kty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=cv::Scalar
1>  ,            _Ty=cv::Scalar
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\type_traits(572) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Kty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=cv::Scalar
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xtree(1023) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<std::less<_Kty>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=cv::Scalar
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\map(70) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=cv::Scalar
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Pr=std::less<cv::Scalar>
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const cv::Scalar,int>>
1>          ]
1>          g:\uom\level 4-s1\research project\coding tests\textextraction\textextraction\source1.cpp(288) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<cv::Scalar,int,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=cv::Scalar
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Can somebody figure out the error in my code or give a better approach to store randomly generated Scalar color values in a Map. The intention to store them in a map is to avoid duplicate color values being generated. I want to prevent generating similar RGB values.

---

Update

---

According to the berak's answer I tried this.

---

```
    RNG rng(0xFFFFFFFF);
    struct ScalarLess
    {
        bool operator()(Scalar &a, Scalar &b)
        {
            return a[0] < b[0]; // bogus, i doubt, that you need *real* sorting
        }
    };
    Scalar randomColorTemp = randomColor(rng);
    map<Scalar, int, ScalarLess> segmentColorsMap;
    segmentColorsMap.insert((pair<Scalar, int>(randomColorTemp, 2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the Scalar as a key for the map, you need to supply a 'Less' operator, so it can sort it. like this:

```
struct ScalarLess
{
   bool operator()(const Scalar &a, const Scalar &b)
   {
       return a[0] < b[0]; // bogus, i doubt, that you need *real* sorting
   }
};


map<Scalar,int,ScalarLess> segmentColors;
```

Comment: Or define `operator<` for `Scalar`.

Comment: @ooga, that would have to be a class member, no ?

Comment: I don't think it would have to be a member.

Comment: I tried this. But still same types of errors.

 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(523): error C2664: 'bool wmain::ScalarLess::operator ()(cv::Scalar &,cv::Scalar &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const cv::Scalar_<double>' to 'cv::Scalar &'
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers

I will add my new code as an update to the question.

Comment: And can u explain what is done by adding a ScarLess member to that map declaration. I am new to c++ and can u please explain briefly about it.

Comment: std::map is sorted. to achieve the sorting, you need some operator doing the comparison.

Comment: @berak sorting is not I want. I just want to  put Scalar objects into a map. How to do that. Your solution failed as I have mentioned above. The overall intention of putting them into a map is expressed in my question.